# How to get wellformed XML of DOM document in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I want to serialize DOM in Javascript and expect to get a well-formed XML document, however `meta` tag is not closed:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="test">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>test
    <pre id='x'/>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('x').appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document))
    );
  </script>
</html>
```

The output contains an invalid XML, where `meta` is not closed. However `p` is closed:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="test">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The same behavior in Chrome 30.0 and Phantomjs 1.9.2.

I'm expecting a well-formed XML output from `XMLSerializer`, even though my HTML input is broken. Why this is not happening and what is a workaround? I need to convert DOM to XML as a text.

Comment: So you want to convert a doc that is NOT well formed into one that is? Browsers don't play by well formed rules unless it is xhtml.

Comment: @MikeCheel I think he's expecting the DOM to be well-formed, even though browsers are tolerant of malformed HTML.

Comment: @Barnar Right that's what I am saying. Unless it is xhtml you won't be able to expect anything well formed (and browsers fill stuff in as they like too). I think he is going to have to do some massaging to get what he wants.

Comment: @MikeCheel yes, I'm expecting a well-formed XML as an output of `XMLSerializer`. In my example above it produces a text which is not an XML at all. What could be a workaround?

Comment: I think you will have to do it yourself or with a library.

Comment: @Dude can you recommend a library?

Comment: I actually have no clue wheather one even exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's impossible to do with a native `XMLSerializer`. I've found these libraries so far:

- https://github.com/jindw/xmldom
- https://github.com/znerol/node-xmlshim